# D3 spacing between bars

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, bar-chart

I'm new to D3 and was hoping if someone could help me with trying to figure out how I can add some spacing between the individual bars. Here's the code:

```
var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, 420]);

d3.select(".chart")
  .selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")
    .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

I'm following this example to create the bar chart https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/

Answer (score 3):

Give a margin-top like this:

```
d3.select("#chart")
  .selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")
    .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
    .style("background-color", "red")
    .style("margin-top", "10px") //give margin-top for spacing between bars
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/77vc1gk9/)

Comment: Didn't actually consider using margin-top in a .style. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Those bars exist inside DOM as divs, which means that you can use traditional styling of divs to add spacing.

Find this section:

```
.chart div {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}
```

and change `margin: 1px;` to whatever you want the spacing to be.

You should be careful though, because usually d3 doesn't operate on divs, but on SVG or canvas elements. For that, the method for changing bar spacing would be different.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and answer. Seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

`width = 100;`
Try to add `.attr("width", width/data.length - 10)`
Or if you make as in example you need to add "height" attribute to make vertical spaces